# Problems with .net and toolbar, menu & status bar rendermode (blue) and standard form (grey)

Tags: c#, .net, windows, user-interface

[image]

Hiya,
I'm a bit of a newbie to .NET so please ignore my ignorance. If you look at the above image (a  complete prototype, ignore black bits :)) you will see lovely menus, toolbars & statusbars all using windows XP render mode and in a funky blue.
Look at the form, labels, checkboxes and other buttons and you see horrible old school windows grey. These components don't have a render mode.
My question: is there any way to show everything in XP style or do I have to chose new components?
Thx.
A.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like XP style. The button has rounded corners with smooth 3D look (not just "raised box" as the "old school gray" was like).

Here is example of old style grey buttons:
[image]
<sub>(source: [techmynd.com](https://www.techmynd.com/wp-content/uploads/2009/04/old-style-windows.jpg))</sub>

It seems like there are no way of getting the toolbar background as background on the checkbox and button. An alternative is to add them as toolbar buttons instead, using DisplayStyle=Text.

The check box can be replaced with a toolbar button and setting `CheckOnClick=True`. It also has a property `Checked` that can be true or false. If you need tri-state, you can use the property `CheckState` instead.

Answer (score 0):

This is already standard XP style.
Try changing the render mode of the Toolstrip; that may make you happier.

Otherwise, you'll need to move to a third-party component vendor.
I've been using [DevExpress](http://www.devexpress.com/Products/NET/Controls/WinForms/), and I'm very happy with them.